# Codeigniter email function is not working with amazon ses

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, smtp, codeigniter-3

I am using Amazon ses account to send email.

All the credentials are working fine in **core php** with **class.phpmailer.php**

But not working with **codeigniter email class** on **the same server**

And not showing me any error with **echo $this->email->print_debugger();**

Please take a look at code

**core php code**

```
//include phpmailer
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

//SMTP Settings
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
$mail->Host       = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
$mail->Username   = "AKIAIF4U4***5J36ROIA";
$mail->Password   = "AhI9Nn********GSo4u8r0xNK/OI";
//

$mail->SetFrom('donotreply@*****.com', 'medi***'); //from (verified email address)
$mail->Subject = "Email Subject"; //subject

//message
$body = "This is a test message vipul.";
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

//recipient
$mail->AddAddress("vipul.kumar@******.com", "Test Recipient"); 

//Success
if ($mail->Send()) { 
    echo "Message sent!"; die; 
}

//Error
if(!$mail->Send()) { 
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
}
```

**codeigniter code**

```
public function test_aws_email($data=array()){

    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'tls://email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'AKIAIF4U4***5J36ROIA',
        'smtp_pass' => 'AhI9Nn********GSo4u8r0xNK/OI'
    );
    $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from("donotreply@******.com", 'Medi***');
    $this->email->to('vipul.kumar@******.com');
    $this->email->subject('TEST FOR AWS ');
    $this->email->message('AWS AUTHENTICATION CLEAR ');
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

Comment: Remove the tls:// part from the smtp host

Comment: not working even after removing tls://